# Flutter RiverPod: Is it ok to return another provider from build method of Notifier?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I want to keep my return value as `AsyncValue` rather than `Stream` so I am returning `StreamProvider` from `build` method of `Notifier`. After reading the codebase of `riverpod` I can't see any drawback of this, but I have never come across any project doing something like this. Is this fine, or is there any straight forward way to convert `Stream` to `AsyncValue`.

```
final _userProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<User?>((ref) {
  final repository = ref.watch(repositoryProvider);
  return repository.getUser(); //returns Stream<User?>
});

class AuthNotifier extends AutoDisposeNotifier<AsyncValue<User?>> {
  @override
  AsyncValue<User?> build() {
    return ref.watch(_userProvider);
  }

  Future<void> singOut() {
    return ref.read(repositoryProvider).signOut();
  }
}

final authProvider =
    AutoDisposeNotifierProvider<AuthNotifier, AsyncValue<User?>>(
        AuthNotifier.new);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, yes.
Being able to do such a thing is the goal of the `build` method & `ref.watch`

As long as you don't return the provider itself but the value exposed by the provider, there is no problem:

```dart
build() {
  return ref.watch(provider); // OK
}

build() {
  return provider // KO
}
```